# Regex to return false when string that may contain other capital letters other than the first character

Tags: regex, string, capitalization

So far I've got `^[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]+`

Which works with, for example, John

However it also works for JohnSmith when I want the match to return false if this is the case and the string contains another Capital letter within it

Comment: By the way, `{1}` can always be omitted. Every regex token matches exactly once unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Yes you're right, was a long morning :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[A-Z][^A-Z]+$
```

Just add `$` anchor to make sure it matches the whole and there are no partial matches.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/xO3rH2/3

Without `$` your regex make a partial match upto `John` in `JohnSmith`

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches `John` as a substring of `JohnSmith`, so you either need to use an additional end-of-string [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`$`) or choose a regex function that forces the entire string to match. Since not all languages have such a function, here's a solution with anchors:

```
^[A-Z][^A-Z]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to accept a single capitol letter as well:

```
^[A-Z][^A-Z]*$
```

Othwise use

```
^[A-Z][^A-Z]+$
```

which accepts a capitol letter with at least one non-capitol letter appended.

Comment: Hey, pretty awesome! It worked as smooth as a piece of butter in a pan :)